# get value from result of conditioned loop with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

how to get the value of the loop that is not the value of the array [0, 2, 3,4], I put this array in the "Bulan" variable.

let's say I have the result value of the loop 0 - 11 (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) and I want to get the value (1,5,6,7,8 ,9,10,11)

```
const d = new Date();
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var dataWaktu = [];
var dataIzin = [];
var dataCuti = [];
var dataSakit = [];

var Bulan = []; //[0,2,3,4]
var dataLeave = [];

for (var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
    var existData = true; 
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
        if(val.Bulan == monthNames[i] ){ 
            // console.log(i);
            Bulan.push(val.Bulan);
            existData = true; return; 
        } else {
            // console.log(i);
            existData = false;  
        }
    });
    
    if(existData){
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
            dataLeave.push({ Bulan: val.Bulan, Cuti: val.Cuti, Izin: val.Izin, Sakit: val.Sakit });
        });
    } else {
        //output : 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
        // dataLeave.push({ Bulan:monthNames[i], Cuti: 0, Izin: 0, Sakit:0 });
        console.log(i); //0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var Bulan = [0,2,3,4];

// create new array of monthNumber that are needed
var monthNumbers = []

for (let i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++){
    if (Bulan.includes(i) === false){
        monthNumbers.push(i)
    }
}

console.log(monthNumbers) // it will show [1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

Comment: if i put 0.2,3,4 into an array, how to do it?, i've looped through this array and created a condition, the result is 1, 2, 3(2), 5(4), etc.

Comment: I already update the answer, is that what you means? @creatorlife

Comment: Hei? Could you tell if it`s already right or not by using check or upvote..? so the community will understand if later meet the same problem like you @creatorlife

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
  let numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
  let numbersToRemove = [0,2,3,4];
  let newNumbers = numbers.filter(number => !numbersToRemove.includes(number) );

  console.log(newNumbers) // 1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```